# How to play songs in the media element when i selected from listbox control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

i have 7 songs in list box control.if i selected those songs from listbox that songs should be play in media element?

please help me..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Listbox` `SelectionChanged` event for changing the`MediaElement` `source` property like

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement1.Source = new Uri(FilePath);
    }
```

You will get more informatin about this in [MediaElement in wpf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/453/)